# How do I write an AngularJS Directive for Pagination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write an AngularJS Directive that helps me with pagination. I want the user to be able to see up to 5 numbered links (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) when searching for something. If there are more than 5 pages of results they will be able to click an arrow > and see links 6 - 10 and so on.

This is what I have so far, note that I am not sure how to complete the 'element.attr' line:

```
var ReportsApp = angular.module('ReportsApp', []);

ReportsApp.directive('paginate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
    scope: {
        page: '=page'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var page = scope.page;
        updatePage();

        function updatePage() {
            if (page <= 5) {
                for (page = 1; page <= 5; page++) {
                    element.attr('paginate')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

The html is:

```
  <div id="pages">
    <a href="#" paginate page="p"></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a template and angular ng-repeat instead? something like this:

```
template: '<div id="pages">
            <a href="#" paginate page="n" ng-repeat="n in pages" ></a>
        </div>'
```

here is a sample where this goes:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
    scope: {
        page: '=page'
    },
    template: '<div id="pages">
        <a href="#" paginate page="n" ng-repeat="n in pages" ></a>
    </div>'
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    ...
```

Comment: However, I must highlight that pagers already exist for angular if you google them: http://jsfiddle.net/zZURe/14/

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like similar for my project. Please check the below code.
User this directive on any html element which is having **vertical scrolling**.

```js
(function(ng) {
    'use strict';
    ng.module('commonUtilsModule')

    /**
        This directive used to load records from backend when mouse is scrolling down
    */
    .directive('fosWhenScrolled', function() {
        return function(scope, elm, attr) {
            var raw = elm[0];

            elm.bind('scroll', function() {
                if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                    scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
                }
            });
        };
    });


}(angular));
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12" fos-when-scrolled="fetchResults()"></div>
```